# Smoke coming from my exhaust

Tags: smoke

I have a 2015 Dodge Dart, white smoke is coming from my exhaust when I’m diving, but there is no loss of coolant and it’s not overheating

Comment: What color is the smoke? Pure White? Greyish/Bluish? Is this Constant or only on start up? Every time you Rev it, does it puff smoke? Out of the tail-pipe at the back OR somewhere in between?

Answer (score 1):

This may not be a problem - if it is a whiteish smoke then it is probably water vapour condensing in the atmospheric conditions.